# Cannot start a basic web server (using node.js) on an AWS instance

Tags: node.js, http, web, amazon-web-services

I have a free AWS instance with node.js installed. I took the following code from the Node Beginner Book (http://www.nodebeginner.org/) -

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

and put it in a file called server.js with the intent to test a basic web server. However, when I run it using `node server.js`, it simply hangs and doesn't return anything. Can anyone suggest what I might try to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: When I run the code on my local machine, it hangs as on AWS but if I go to http://localhost:8888/, the server appears to be running.

Comment: as nightgaunt said in his answer it's the Security Groups that you need to adjust in order to allow incoming traffic on port 8888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing what it's supposed to do. It's running in a loop waiting for connections, not hanging.

If you connect to it with a browser, you will get the desired output (in the browser). There will be no output in console where your running the server (as per your code).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but may be you are not running the node process as deamon or using nohup and hence you feel as though it's hung. Why don't you add a couple of `console.log` in your code and check?

In amazon AWS instance, you need to configure ports that are accessible. Check the security group tab in your amazon EC2 console.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question here: [Node JS "Hello world" server on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998224/node-js-hello-world-server-on-aws/23440342#23440342).

I think your problem is with port numbers and firewalls, you might need to:

1. Allow port in AWS console (all traffic or just 80)
2. Change port from 8888 to 80 or user iptables redirect
3. Turn off EC2 instance firewall (describe in the other answer) or accept inbound and outbound port 80 requests