# AWS front-end back-end communication

Tags: reactjs, symfony, amazon-web-services, routes, reverse-proxy

I have 2 apps running on ASW Symfony on port 8000 (local) and react 3000(local) but accessible through TCP on port 80 redirections was achieved by listening of port 80 within nginx server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.info  www.example.info;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.info  www.example.info;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

}
```

I have tried to listen and redirect of two ports but without success. 
Within the server, Symfony application is accessible with curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
From outside in my react app I am sending api requests to asw.external.ip (123.123.123.123:800) but I get timeout. How could I access my back-end from outside?

Comment: Did you configure your Security Groups in the right way? You need to whitelist Inbound calls to port 8000

Comment: 1. You'll use a React application in CloudFront (super easy to use it). I'll help you with that, if you needed to.

Comment: 2. Your API application will intercept using nginx port. I'll put a example to you.

Comment: Have you checked the nginx logs? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### AWS ElasticBeanstalk - Configuring the Proxy Server to your back-end

You can use this config file to your Aws Ec2 as well.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

```
  upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    keepalive 256;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ## Optional configuration if you want to allow AWS 
    ## to cache your static files
    location /static {
        alias /var/app/current/static;
    }
  }
```

#### Edit - Configuring Nginx for Symfony

```
server {
    listen             8080;
    server_name        sf2testproject.dev;

    root /home/maurits/public_html/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        # rewrite all to app.php
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Where:

- `listen` is the port that your application communicate with the world.
- `fastcgi_pass` is a binary protocol for interfacing interactive programs with a web server

References:

- [Aws ElasticBeanstalk - Nodejs platform proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html)
- [Symfony Hhvm 3 nginx 1.4 vs PHP 5.5 apache 2.4](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/05/symfony-hhvm-3-nginx-1-4-vs-php-5-5-apache-2-4/)
- [FastCGI Oficial Example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/)

Comment: With proxy, it's working, but now it is even worse because I don't understand it :) So I am listening and redirecting the 80 port it two places /etc/nginx/sites-available/default as in my original question and now I have added /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf as in your example. How is it happening that my frontend is rendered from node on local port 3000 and I have access to api on port 8000 local where is my symfony just calling http 80 from outside?

Comment: 1. So.. You can backup your `default` file as `/etc/nginx/backup/default.bkp` and test it using mine.

Comment: 2. To understand better, you can test it adding `server_name` and some more.

Comment: 3. Nginx does your proxy conf communicate with world using port 80 and a proxy port to communicate with your back-end app. I updated my answer above. ;)

Comment: one more question, how could I manage more redirects here in proxy, if I want another node.js running on local port 3001 how can I access it from outside when I already have access to port 3000(react-app) and 8000(symfony-app)? Thank you.

Comment: You just need to add one more nginx configuration OR start a node.js app withou nginx and configure AWS group security to your 3001 port to comunicate with the world.https://stackoverflow.com/a/23440342/3332734 and https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171